# Type Of Random Variable When Given That Joint Distribution Is Discrete.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $Z=(X,Y)$ is discrete random  variable with support $S\subset \Bbb R^2$.
Is it true that $X$ and $Y$ are discrete?

My attempt :

Define $A=\left \{ x\in \Bbb R : (x,y) \in S ~~\text{for some}~ y\in \Bbb R \right\}.$ and $B=\left \{ y\in \Bbb R : (x,y) \in S ~~\text{for some}~ x\in \Bbb R \right\}.$ then $A\times B$ is countable and  $S\subset A\times B$.
Now
$$
\begin{align}
1=P(Z\in S)&\leq P(Z \in A\times B)\\~\\
&=P(X\in A,Y\in B)\\~\\
&\leq P(X\in A)
\end{align}$$
So we have $P(X\in A)=1$ where $A$ is countable set . Similarly $P(Y\in B)=1$. Hence $X$ and $Y$ are discrete.

> Is my Claim and proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define discrete by "at most countable support", it's even more basic than that. Notice that the projections onto the supports of $X$ and $Y$ are surjections, so their image is at most the cardinality of $S$, which was countable. In symbols: $|\mathrm{supp}(X)| = |\pi_x(S)| \leq |S|$, where the inequality uses surjectivity.

Comment: I didn't get your point . support of the $X$ is the thing that we find here .

Comment: $|\mathrm{supp}(X)| = |\pi_x (S)| \leq |S|$

Comment: Set $A$ is just $\pi_{x}(S)$ .

Comment: I want to show $X$ and $Y$ are discrete. You said $A$ is not by definition **support** right?

Comment: What I said is that the support of $X$ is the projection of $S$ onto the $x$-axis. You don't need to involve any probabilities for this.

Comment: Since domain is countable support must be . much easier then mine . thank you